# Getting all Appointments which are in a certain Date range in Sequel

Tags: ruby, database, date, range, sequel

I have the following problem: I have a database connected via Sequel. I have to get all Appointments from a certain range of Dates.

The problem is, that the appointments can repeat and the database layout is like so (after sequel):

```
{
  :start_date => Date,
  :repeats => Integer,
  :repeat_unit => Integer
}
```

Whereas the repeat unit is mapped like so:

```
0 = Daily
1 = Weekly
2 = Every second week
3 = Every third week
4 = Every fourth week
```

I have a range of dates (like `(Date.today..Date.today+1)`) and have to check retreive all Appointments which are in this range.

What I have by now:

```
class Appointment < Sequel::Model

  def self.in_range(range)
    Appointment.directly_in_range(range).or.repeated_in_range(range)
  end

  def self.directly_in_range(r)
    self.where do |a|
      a.start_date > r.first
    end.and.where do |a|
      a.start_date < r.last
    end
  end

  def self.repeated_in_range(r)
    # TODO
  end

end
```

How to implement the latter method? What does sequel offer to approach this problem?

Comment: Which database are you using? The proper answer will probably involve usage of database-specific features. Postgres for example has great features that will make it a bit simpler to do complex queries. The answer would probably look different with MySQL for example.

Comment: If I have an appointment that repeats every week and the query is over a range of multiple weeks, should the appointment be in the results repeatedly or only once?

Comment: Is `repeats` the number of repetitions?

Comment: Answer to all three questions: postgresql, but I would prefer a generic solution. I have to select all appointments in a given range. so if an appointment appears in the range, I want this appointment, still. `repeats` is the number of repetitions, yes.

Answer (score 0):

> How to implement the latter method?  What does sequel offer to approach this problem?

I'm not sure how your question has anything to do with Sequel?  You can get all the appointments from Appointment.directly_in_range(), and then do something like this:

```
results = []

appointments.each do |appointment|
  the_date = appointment.date
  repeats = appointment.repeats

  while (the_date = the_date + repeats*7) < r.last
      results << the_date
  end
```

But really, I fail to see how there are any other appointment objects than those returned by Appointment.directly_in range()??  Do you want to create new Appointment objects using the forward dates?  If so,

```
  while (the_date = the_date + repeats*7) < r.last
    results << Appointment.new(the_date, repeats, appointment.repeat_units)
  end
```

Comment: The problem is, that `directly_in_range()` returns only appointments which are _in_ the range. If an appointment is not in the range, but repeatet weekly, which results as (lets call it) virtual appointment in the range, I have to catch it anyways.

Comment: I would like to solve this with sequel as a non-sequel solution would cause heavy load on the database, as each Appointment object has to be queried and checked with ruby. A pure sequel solution wouldn't cause every appointment to be loaded as ruby object.

Comment: **The problem is...** Ah, I see.  You could have a range which is in the future, beyond an appointment's start_date.  And then the repeat would make the appointment fall within the range.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally got it.

My querying algorithm uses unions now, which might not be the best (most performant) solution to the problem, but at least I got it working in pure sequel, so it it doesn't create load on the DB by fetching the whole table for parsing in ruby.

Here is my implementation of the *whole* algorithm to the described problem:

```
  def self.in_range(r)
    Appointment.where(:start_date => r).union(
        Appointment.where do |a| # daily-repeating into union
          a.start_date + a.repeats > r.first
        end.where(:repeat_unit => 0)
      ).union(
        Appointment.where do |a| # (nondaily) repeating into union
          a.start_date + (a.repeats * a.repeat_unit * 7) > r.first
          # We don't care about the :repeat_unit => 0 entries here, as if
          # they appear outside of our range, the zero will keep them from
          # arriving here and if they are in we select them anyways
        end
      ).exclude { |a| a.start_date > r.last }
  end
```

I did some verification using pure Ruby:

```
# Helper for checking if the element is in the range on its own
def in_range(e, r)
  r.include? e.start_date
end

# Helper for checking if the element gets repeated into the range
def repeated_into_range(e, r)
  if e.repeat_unit == 0
    _e = e.start_date + e.repeats
  else
    _e = e.start_date + e.repeats * e.repeat_unit * 7
  end

  r.first < _e and not e.start_date > r.last
end

# Helper for checking a whole set, if all elements appear
# on either of the both ways described for the other
# helpers inside the range
def verify(set, range)
  set.map do |element|
    in_range(element, range) or repeated_into_range(element, range)
  end
end
```

I *guess* this is a complete solution to the problem.

---

Edit: As someone asked in the comments to this post, here is the sql output of my filter, with some newlines inserted for readability:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM "appointment" WHERE 
        (
            ("start_date" >= '2014-09-05') 
            AND 
            ("start_date" <= '2014-09-05')
        ) 
        UNION 
        (
            SELECT * FROM "appointment" WHERE 
            (
                (
                    ("start_date" + "repeats") > '2014-09-05'
                ) 
                AND 
                ("repeat_unit" = 0)
            )
        )
) AS "t1" UNION 
(
    SELECT * FROM "appointment" WHERE 
    (
        ("start_date" + ("repeats" * "repeat_unit" * 7)) > '2014-09-05')
    )
) AS "t1" WHERE ("start_date" <= '2014-09-05')
```

Called with `Appointment.in_range(Date.today..Date.today).sql`.

Comment: What do you get when you do `.sql` on your filter?

Comment: @7stud Added in my answer.